# After successful installation aws-cdk, cdk command not found

Tags: npm, installation, aws-cdk

I am installing aws-cdk on windows using powershell,

First I was getting Error : "\AppData\Roaming\npm' npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file."

during installation. I fixed that by creating folder "\AppData\Roaming\npm" as recommended by some solution.

Now my installation is successful with "npm i -g aws-cdk". No error reported,

but when I do "cdk --version" I am getting "cdk : The term 'cdk' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

"npm -g ls --depth=0" returns
C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- aws-cdk@1.72.0

Answer (score 7):

1. Install AWS-CDK:

   ```
   npm i -g aws-cdk
   ```
2. run below command to set path of environment variable:

   ```
   setx PATH "D:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm"
   ```
3. close the command prompt once above command successfully executed.
4. open command prompt as new session and run below command:

   ```
   cdk --version
   ```

Answer (score 6):

There are many reasons this could be happening, some of them likely Windows-specific. It is probably worth it to chase down the issue, but for a quick "just get the command running" solution, you can use `npx` to install-and-execute rather than `npm` to install.

```
$ npx -p aws-cdk cdk --version
1.72.0 (build c2f38e8)
$
```

Comment: This saved me after hours of banging my head against a wall. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I used `npx cdk --version` instead of `cdk --version` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

The above solution may work, but I was able to make mine work by adding "\AppData\Roaming\npm" to user Path variable.

Comment: Make sure you put your username in for <username> correctly, or you will get:

`The system cannot find the file specified. `

Answer (score 0):

If you made the mistake of installing cdk with pip at some point in time, make sure to remove it.

```
pip uninstall cdk
```

You could check if you have it installed with:

```
pip list | grep cdk
```

Answer (score 0):

**On windows**, make sure you don't have two versions of node in your path.  For example, after installing latest node, I was having issues with `cdk`.  Then I typed

```
where.exe node
```

Only to find it had been installed implicitly with another windows program

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft HPC Pack 2012\Bin\node.exe
```

I had to put the correct node earlier in the path - the order of path variables determines priority.