# Problem with aws cdk on Windows 10 Home Edition (Code: 800A03F6 Source: Compilation Error in Microsoft JScript)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am installing aws-cdk on windows 10 home edition using powershell as administrator.

After successful installation and calling cdk - version, I keep getting error messages from the Windows Script Host:  

Script  
C:\Users..\ApData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\bin\cdk.js  
line 1  
Character 1  
...  
Code: 800A03F6  
Source: Compilation Error in Microsoft JScript  

To solve the problem

- I tried npx -p aws-cdk cdk --version.
- I uninstalled node and aws-cdk, restarted windows and reinstalled everything.

Everything without success.  

Error 800A03F6 can mean anything and only occurs in connection with cdk --version command. I don't have a proxy and have used an antivirus program.

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed this problem by changing the path in the environment variable:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67566915/12408270

change environment variable PATH to:
C:\Users\${your_username}\AppData\Roaming\npm